# Team Viewer hangs remote window

Tags: windows

I am having problems with TeamViewer, i connect to remote PC, it accepts the ID and the PW, but then the remote window screen is never shown, i wait and wait and nothing comes up.

Someone ever had such problem and ever found solution ?

If its because of slow connection speed probably no way to solve it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teamviewer takes a long time sometimes to verify the connection. Teamviewer is also known for "long timeouts", especially when the remote's pc got disconnected. Try this as an alternative : http://www.join.me